# Can i use multiple jar to submit a job to flink cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have a flink job and it expects another dependency jar to be available at run time. Is it possible to submit a job with multiple jars in flink cluster. I can not build one common jar.

Comment: You cannot make one uber jar with all the dependencies in it? Can I ask why?

Comment: I am using Java reflection and main jar is already deployed in prod., Now user have to use their dependent jar while submitting the job. Do I have to build uber jar every time which I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes, you should have everything wrapped in an uber jar that you upload to the cluster. You only have to upload it to the cluster once though. Then the user(s) can choose to submit a job with an uploaded build.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the dependency jar on every flink node in the flink/lib folder as described [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/monitoring/debugging_classloading.html#avoiding-dynamic-classloading). That would make it available to user uploaded jars without the need for your users to bundle it with their jars.

Keep in mind that this would be handled entirely outside of the job submission API, so you would have to incorporate it into whatever system you're using to manage configuration on your flink nodes.